# iOS multiple video display

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, sdl, rtsp, ijkplayer

I'm currently doing an iOS project that uses `IJKPlayer` which is based on `FFmpeg` and `SDL` to display RTSP feed from a certain source.

I have no problem in displaying a single video feed but my project requires me to display multiple stream on the screen simultaneously, the problem I'm facing right now is to separate each of the streams and display it on `n` number of instances of player.

```
RTSP -> stream 0, stream 1, stream 2, stream 4 -> display
```

Here is a sample output I want to achieve. Each color represents a single stream. Thanks!

[image]

Edit: If this is not possible on IJKPlayer, can someone recommend a different approach on how to implement this?

Comment: what is the actual problem? if the number of feed is not fixed then just use a collection view and put your player inside each cell.

Comment: problem is that a only have 1 url that contains multiple stream, if I put the player inside a collectionView wouldn't it make different instances and load repeatedly the same link? Probably it will.

Answer (score 0):

See the QuickBlox SDK here: [QuickBlox SDK](https://quickblox.com/developers/IOS). Does exactly what you need here.

Comment: Nope. Sorry, the higher-ups does not want to use that SDK.

Comment: This does not mean you can't use its architecture from example implementation of the video-calling client (I was using that to inject 3rd party video streams and add a face-tracking features to QuickBlox).